# LINQ compare lists and update property with values from found object

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists with same object type(Lets say list A and B). Object has property *amount*. Is there way with using linq to compare first list with second one and when object from list A is found in list B (by ID), update object's, in list A, *amount* and set it be old value minus amount of object in list B.

```
  List A                         List B                     Result list
    ID  Name      Amount        ID  Name   Amount      ID   Name    Amount
    5   obj1       5            5   obj1    1           5    obj1    4
    9   obj2       4            9   obj2    2           9    obj2    2
    16  obj3       3            16  obj3    3           16   obj3    0
```

Kind regards,

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please include the code you have that is not working

Comment: What if there are multiple with the same ID's in ListB?

Comment: Thank You all for answers, for start I used simple two foreach loops, but I figured maybe there is less consuming method since in while those lists might be large. And Yes, there might be duplicates in list B foreach (Article a in full_material_list)
            {
                foreach (Article b in used_material_list)
                {
                    if (a.ArticleID == b.ArticleID)
                    {
                        a.ArticleAmount = a.ArticleAmount - b.ArticleAmount;
                    }}}
I will try Tim's solution also. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a join:

```
var query = from a in ListA join b in ListB on a.ID equals b.ID
            select new{ A = a, NewValue = a.Amount - b.Amount };
foreach(var x in query)
    x.A.Amount = x.NewValue;
```

This is more efficient since `Join` uses a set based approach and also only updates if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
listA.ForEach(obj => 
{
    obj.Amount -= listB.SingleOrDefault(other => obj.Id == other.Id)?.Amount ?? 0;
}
```

This iterates over listA and substracts listB corresponding Amount if there's one, substracts 0 otherwise (do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

i would go for a simple loop since i find it more readable in these cases (personal opinion)

```
foreach(MyObj o in A)
{
   IEnumerable<MyObj> supp = B.Where(b => b.Name == o.Name);
   if(supp != null)
   {
     foreach(MyObj ob in supp)
     {
       o.Amount -= ob.Amount;
     }
   }
}
```